# I can't use if statements because invalid syntax

Tags: python, if-statement

It won't let me run this code. I don't get why.
Here is the code: https://repl.it/G7Kx

```
print ("Whose team are you on?")
die = int(raw_input("1.) Mine    (2.) Yours"))
if die == "1"
print ("good")
```

Comment: Sorry, I was a complete noob then, I understand now. Anyways, thanks to all who were willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure your code is properly and regularly indented, as that is how Python decides what is and isn't included in the if statement.

Second, you must add a colon after the condition or it will be a syntax error.

Your code should look like this:

```
print("Whose team are you on?")
die = int(input("1 - Mine     2 - Yours"))
if die == 1:
    print("good")
else:            #This is optional but always nice to include
    print("bad")
```

Comment: Nice solution! Now you should work on editing answer!

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at your code, and there were a lot of errors. For one, you need to indent and use a colon when you use an if statement. That's why you were getting an invalid syntax error.

However, try this code below. It lets the user input their decision and prints "good" if they choose "Mine".

```
die = input ("Whose team are you on? Mine or yours?")
if die == "Mine":
    print ("good")
```

Hope this helps!